Integral calculation $ \int_\gamma \frac{\sqrt{z+1/2}}{z^2+1/4}dz $ along a self-Intersecting Curve in $\mathbb{C}$
I'm trying to calculate the integral: $\gamma:[0,1]\to \mathbb{C},\gamma(t)=\sin(8\pi t)+i\cos(4\pi t)$
$$
\int_\gamma \frac{\sqrt{z+1/2}}{z^2+1/4}dz
$$
where $\sqrt{\ }$ is the principle value with domain $\mathbb{C}\backslash\mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$.
I try at first to calculate by definition (turn it to a real integral), but then it becomes extremely complicated. Then I want to use Cauchy's integral formula, but the integrand has two poles in denominator. I also tried to decomposite it to two fraction, but I don't know how to deal the numerator. In addition, the curve is although closed, but it is self-intersected, I'm not sure if this affects the application of some integral theorems.

Actually I am. But I think it's hard to calculate the residuum for this function. By the way, this is a homework problem from a complex analysis course, but the course hasn't yet covered the residue theorem or even Laurent series. So I am wondering if it can be solved using some elementary methods. But if you can solve it use residue theorem, I'm also glad to hear about it.

The curve $\underline{is\ not\ closed}$ when $t \in \left[0,1\right]$ as you defined it. However, $\underline{it's\ closed}$ when $t \in \left[0,\pi/2\right]$.

Hi @FelixMarin I think rather the function is not simple closed but it is closed.

First, it is a good idea to plot the contour. See here
Second, note that the function
$$f(z) =  \frac{\sqrt{z+1/2}}{z^2+1/4}$$
has a branch point at $\displaystyle z = -\frac{1}{2}$ which is not inside the contour. If we take the branch cut $(-\infty,-\frac{1}{2})$ and the principal branch of $\sqrt{z+\frac{1}{2}}$ the function it is analytic in the contour and we can apply the residue theorem.
Third. Note that both poles are inside the contour.
Edit: The upper half of the contour runs two times in the clockwise direction and has winding number $-2$ while the contour in the lower-half runs two times in the counter-clockwise direction and has winding number $2$.
Hence, by the residue theorem:
\begin{eqnarray*}\oint_{\gamma}  \frac{\sqrt{z+1/2}}{z^2+1/4} dz&=& 2\pi i \left[2\operatorname{Res}\left(f(z), -\frac{i}{2}\right)- 2\operatorname{Res}\left(f(z), \frac{i}{2}\right)\right]\\
&=&2\pi i\left[2i\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}} +2i \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}} 
\right]\\
&=&-4\pi \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}} -  4\pi \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}} \\
&=& 2^{\frac{7}{4}}\pi \left[-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)
 -i \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)
 +i \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)\right]\\
&=& -2^{\frac{11}{4}}\pi 
  \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)
\\
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence
$$  \boxed{\oint_{\gamma} \frac{\sqrt{z+1/2}}{z^2+1/4} dz = -2^{\frac{11}{4}}\pi 
  \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right) }$$
Edit 2:
To complement the answer I'm going to put here one definition and one theorem explicitly:

Definition. Let $\gamma$ be a closed curve in $\mathbb{C}$; $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$ is a point not in $\gamma$. Then the index of $\gamma$ with respect to $z_0$ (also called the winding number of $\gamma$ with respect to $z_0$) is defined by $$ I(\gamma,z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{z-z_0} $$


Theorem (Residue Theorem). Let $A$ be a region and let $z_1,...,z_n\in A$ be $n$ distinct points in $A$. Let $f$ be analytic on $A\setminus\left\{z_1,z_2,...,z_n\right\}$; that is, $f$ is analytic on $A$ except for isolated singularities at $z_1,...,z_n$. Let $\gamma$ be a closed curve in $A$ homotopic to a point in $A$. Assume that no $z_i$ lies on $\gamma$. Then $$ \oint_{\gamma} f(z) dz = 2\pi i \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[\operatorname{Res}(f(z),z_i)I(\gamma,z_i) \right]$$

Lets calculate one of the winding numbers for our integral.
\begin{eqnarray*} I\left(\gamma,\frac{i}{2}\right) &=& \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{8\pi \cos(8\pi t)-4\pi i\sin(4\pi t)}{\sin(8\pi t)+i\cos(4\pi t) - \frac{i}{2}}dt\\
&=& \frac{1}{\pi i} \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{8\pi \cos(8\pi t)-4\pi i\sin(4\pi t)}{\sin(8\pi t)+i\cos(4\pi t) - \frac{i}{2}}dt \quad \textrm{(The integrand is $\frac{1}{2}$-periodic)}\\
 &=&\frac{1}{\pi i} \left. \ln\left(\sin(8\pi t)+i\cos(4\pi t) - \frac{i}{2}\right)\right|_{0+}^{\frac{1}{2}-}\\
&=& -2
\end{eqnarray*}
Similarly,
\begin{eqnarray*} I\left(\gamma,-\frac{i}{2}\right) &=& 2
\end{eqnarray*}

Hi Oscar, I find out that the upper half runs two times in the clockwise direction while the lower runs two times in the counterclockwise direction. See here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ParametricPlot%5B%7Bsin%288pix%29%2Ccos%284pix%29%7D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C3%2F16%7D%5D

I have to repost. Limiting comment edits to five minutes causes me to say words that would get me kicked off this forum.

$=-2^{7/4}\pi\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}$, eliminating the trig function. I agree with all else, +1.
